# Help with MySQL (.sql) and Shell Script

Tags: mysql, shell, scripting, sed, os.system

How do I call the following in a .sql file?

```
mysql -u username -h serverip db -e "select a, b, c, d from mytable" > '/home/dump/result.txt';
```

I will then have to convert the tab separated file to csv for which I want to use sed.

1. Is there a way to do it all in one
   line? (append sed command to convert
   the .txt file to csv)
2. How to use an
   os.system call in .sql file? Will it
   work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql --batch --skip-column-names -u username -h serverip db \
  -e "select a, b, c, d from mytable" \
  | sed -e 's/\t/,/g' \
  > '/home/dump/result.txt'
```

See docs for [`--batch`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_batch) and [`--skip-column-names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_skip-column-names) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Bill. We are migrating from a scenario where db server and client are the same to individual servers for both. I have a bunch of .sql files with select into outfile queries which won't work anymore. Is there a way to execute your solution in the .sql file itself?

Comment: The mysql client does not have any option to output directly to CSV.  You're going to have to add the `sed` command to your scripts that invoke the mysql client.

Answer (score 2):

What about to run this query via `mysql` console client:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... INTO OUTFILE  '/path/to/file.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
```

Comment: I don't have this option cos' the client server and db server are different. Thanks!